# Zombie giant unkillable task blocks Druid at restart

Tags: druid

I'm running Apache Druid 0.17 deploying with `nohup ./bin/start-nano-quickstart > mylog.log`. As the deep storage I am using s3 and I have `parquet` extension enabled and all work fine. I could ingest with several *small* spark partitioned parquet datasources from s3 correctly. All the remaining configurations are untouched.

As I tried loading a giant datasource to test the performance and resource usage the task died after a couple of hours because of OutOfMemory.(It was expected)

```
2020-02-07T17:32:20,519 INFO [task-runner-0-priority-0] org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.BaseAppenderatorDriver - New segment[arc_2016-09-29T12:00:00.000Z_2016-09-29T13:00:00.000Z_2020-02-07T17:22:45.965Z] for sequenceName[index_parallel_arc_chgindko_2020-02-07T14:59:32.337Z].
Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Now every time I restart Druid, it starts that giant task and it is impossible to kill it. Even when the task apparently dies or turns in waiting status the CPU usage is about 140% and I cannot submit new tasks to Druid. I tried to access the Derby database manually to find the task and remove it but I was not successful and this solution is really nasty. I know that I can change the database in the configuration so the next time I will have a fresh Druid but it is not a good solution as I will miss all other datasources. How can I get ready of this long running zombie task?